# What is the meaning of this code?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, ado.net, indexed-properties

Here is the code sample provided in .Net Sdk:

```
Private Sub ReadOrderData(ByVal connectionString As String)
    Dim queryString As String = _
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        ' Call Read before accessing data.
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", _
                reader(0), reader(1)))
        End While

        ' Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

My question: Is that this **reader(0)** actually the shortcut for calling this property **reader.item(0)**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reader(0)` refers to the very first field in the retrieved row. However you better reference field by name, `OrderID` in this case.

Take a look at [SqlDataReader.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y64yaah2.aspx).

This is indexed property. You can find some details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229061%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I know the purpose, but when creating our own class, we need to add our methods and properties, right? In this case, a call to reader(0) actually a call to which sub, function, or property for the SqlDataReader class?

Comment: @Dee Jay - SqlDataReader.Item. There is a reference in the answer.

Comment: You mean Item property of the SqlDataReader class, right? Ok, if I were creating my own class and wish to have same behaviour like this SqlDataReader class, can I just declare the item property and the call the instance of my class just like current reader(0) call? Do I need to add anything (implement or inherit something)?

Comment: @Dee Jay -  you are looking for 'indexed property'. I added a reference to MSDN to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

reader(0) , reader (1) and so on refers to columns/ fields of the row u r retriving,

reader(0)---> column 1

reader(1)---> column 2
...

You can use direct field names in place of these 'readers'. But in books/tutorials, code is always written like that.